# How do I simplify an easy equation?

Tags: algebra, maxima, simplification

I've got this little equation:

```
4*q+5*(1-q)=6*q+3*(1-q);
```

`ratsimp` simplifies both sides independently:

```
ratsimp(%);

5−q=3*q+3
```

but how would I turn it into `4*q=2`, or `4*q-2=0`?

(Obviously `solve` will give `q=1/2`, what I mean is how to do I get maxima to do the 'change of side is change of sign' thing that I'd do myself if you asked me to simplify the equation)

Comment: Please forgive me for wanting to do something you don't approve of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `ratsimp(lhs(%) - rhs(%) = 0);` ?